# table-layout: fixed; not working when text overflows a cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

The following table should have all columns sized by the given widths in pixels:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col style="width: 50px">
  <col style="width: 40px">
  <col style="width: 30px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>supersuperlooooongcontent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, although `overflow: hidden` is set on the `td` elements, the long text makes the entire column expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `width` to the `table` element, in addition to `table-layout: fixed;`, to obtain desired behavior. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

> Cells use the overflow property to determine whether to clip any overflowing content, **but only if the table has a known width**; otherwise, they won't overflow the cells.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:120px;

}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col style="width: 50px">
  <col style="width: 40px">
  <col style="width: 30px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>supersuperlooooongcontent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked a treat. It also works well with animating widths as long as both values are changed within the same animation frame.